# Extraction all values between special characters SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the following values in the SQL Server table:

[image: input]

But I need to build query from which output look like this:

[image: output]

I know that I should probably use combination of substring and charindex but I have no idea how to do it.

Could you please help me how the query should like?

Thank you!

Comment: which SQL engine are you using? and If I understand correctly you want to explode array right?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server 2019, yes i need to get the each values and have it  like in the output it means for example that offerId = 1 will be three rows with each of the values from the contractType array

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it may work.

```
SELECT 
  offerId, 
  cTypes   
FROM yourTable AS mt  
CROSS APPLY  
EXPLODE(mt.contractTypes) AS dp(cTypes);
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work i have following error:'EXPLODE' is not a recognized function name.

Answer (score 0):

The data in each row in the `contractTypes` column is a valid JSON array, so you may use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with explicit schema (result is a table with columns defined in the `WITH` clause) to parse this array and get the expected results:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   offerId int,
   contractTypes varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (offerId, contractTypes)
VALUES
   (1, '[   "Hlavni pracovni pomer"      ]'),
   (2, '[   "ÖCVS", "Staz", "Prahovne"   ]')
```

Table:

```
SELECT d.offerId, j.contractTypes
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.contractTypes) WITH (contractTypes varchar(100) '$') j
```

Result:

```
offerId contractTypes
1       Hlavni pracovni pomer
2       ÖCVS
2       Staz
2       Prahovne
```

As an additional option, if you want to return the position of the contract type in the `contractTypes` array, you may use `OPENJSON()` with default schema (result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the value in the `key` column is the 0-based index of the element in the array):

```
SELECT 
   d.offerId, 
   CONVERT(int, j.[key]) + 1 AS contractId, 
   j.[value] AS contractType
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.contractTypes) j   
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j.[key])
```

Result:

```
offerId contractId  contractType
1       1           Hlavni pracovni pomer
2       1           ÖCVS
2       2           Staz
2       3           Prahovne
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split` function :

```
select t.offerid, trim(translate(tt.value, '[]"', '   ')) as contractTypes
from table t cross apply
     string_split(t.contractTypes, ',') tt(value);
```